# How to use <ul> in a form_for tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the [Tagit](http://webspirited.com/tagit/) Jquery plugin (more specifically, the last demo on the linked page) in my rails app but can't seem to figure out how to use the  element in a `form_for` to get it to work.

In plain html, this works:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#demo5').tagit({maxLength: 140, maxTags: 3});
  });
</script>

<div class="box">
  <ul id="demo5"></ul>
</div>
```

And generates this, which I extracted with Firebug:

```
<div class="box">
  <ul id="demo5" class="tagit">
    <li class="tagit-new">
        <input class="tagit-input ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
    </li>
        <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to implement it as follows:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "tagit" %>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#demo5').tagit({maxLength: 140, maxTags: 3});
  });
</script>

<div class="box">
  <%= form_for @thingy do |f| %>
    Add some tags
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Your tags" %>
      <ul id="demo5" class="tagit">
        <li>
          <%= f.text_field :tag_list, :value => @thingy.tags_from(current_user) %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <p><%= f.submit "Change" %></p>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Which in turn generates:

```
<div class="box">
  <form id="edit_thingy_5" class="edit_thingy" method="post" action="/thingy/5" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
      <input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
      <input type="hidden" value="put" name="_method">
      <input type="hidden" value="abcdefghijklmno=" name="authenticity_token">
    </div>

    Add some tags

    <p>
      <label for="thingy_tag_list">Your tags</label>
    </p>

    <ul id="demo5">
      <input id="thingy_tag_list" type="text" value="tag1, tag2, tag3" size="30" name="thingy[tag_list]">
    </ul>
    <p></p>

    <p>
      <input id="thingy_submit" type="submit" value="Change" name="commit">
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

All the JavaScript files are loading properly and there are no Stylesheet conflicts.

Comment: Any chance you have duplicate DOM ids (demo5) on the page?

Comment: No chance of that. I can change that id to anything and it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

It is important to know that the input box provided by the tagit plugin is not for you to own to play with in your Rails form. Let it be an internal hidden detail of that jquery plugin.

Assuming

```
@thingy.tags_from(current_user)
```

returns an array, you just need to use that list to seed into tagit and when the form is submitted, read the value from tagit and store in the hidden field that you will submit to the server.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "tagit" %>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#demo5').tagit({maxLength: 140, maxTags: 3, initialTags: $("#mytaglist").val()});
    $("form#myform").submit(function(e){
      $("#mytaglist").val($('#demo5').tagit("tags").map(function(e){return e.value;}).get().join());
      return true; // to continue form submission
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="box">
  Add Some Tags
  <ul id="demo5" class="tagit"></ul>
  <%= form_for @thingy, :id => "myform" do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :tag_list, :value => @thingy.tags_from(current_user).join(), :id => "mytaglist" %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Change" %></p>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got some bad, bad HTML there.

1. You can't put a `UL` inside a `P` (you'll notice the browser corrects that by tossing the `ul` out of the paragraph element)
2. You don't have any `LI` elements inside the `UL`. List-items (`LI`s) are the only elements that can be directly inside a list (`UL` or `OL`) element. So to put inputs into a list element, they need to be inside the list-items in that list.

Mostly, though, TagIt seems fairly intent on building the HTML itself, so I don't know if you can build/copy all the generated HTML, and then use TagIt - it doesn't expect it all to exist.

Try this (it basically puts your existing tags into a `data-` attribute, and extracts them when using tagit on the list:

```
<%= form_for @thingy do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Your tags" %>
  <ul id="demo5" name="thingy[tag_list]" data-tags="<%= @thingy.tags_from(current_user) %>"></ul>

  <p><%= f.submit "Change" %></p>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

<% end %>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var tags = $("#demo5").data("tags").split(/\s+/)
    $('#demo5').tagit({
      maxLength: 140,
      maxTags: 3,
      initialTags: tags,
      select: true
    });
  });
</script>
```

You might also/instead want to put your "Add some tags" text inside some semantically-appropriate element

Comment: Having updated/editied the question with the suggested proper HTML, I'm still stuck where I was.

Comment: @Simpleton: I've updated my answer - don't know if it'll work, but I think it's at least closer. Hadn't really looked at TagIt until now

Comment: Thanks dude. Btw with your setup, the input field disappeared so I tried it with <li> elements still in tact and neither worked. I'm going to sleep and maybe a fresh look tomorrow will help.